# PHP resources cannot be identified from backtrace (call stack)

Tags: php

I'm writing PHP method to pretty-print callstack with params. *Reason for this is it will be used as an output of a public API (in debug mode) so it must not display everything and only display save information.*

I would like to see something like this:

> 1. Config->saveToFile(resource: file) in config.php::456
> 2. Config->backup('config.bak') in config.php::123

But when I call `debug_backtrace()` and parse the `args` value, I cannot use methods `gettype()`, `is_resource()` and `get_resource_type()` because it **always say the variable is of unknown type**:

> 1. Config->saveToFile(Unknown type: Resource id #99) in config.php::456
> 2. Config->backup('config.bak') in config.php::123

Code used to parse args is:

```
public static function getTrace() {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $output = [];

    foreach ($trace as $call) {
        $name = $call['class'] . $call['type'] . $call['function']
        //actual code checks for various situations

        $args = [];
        foreach ($call['args'] as $arg) {
            $args[] = self::toString($arg);
        }
        $name .= '(' . join(', ', $args) . ')';

        $output[] = $name . ' in ' . basename($call['file']) . '::' . $call['line'];
    }

    return $output;
}
protected static function toString($mixed) {
    //process known types - arrays, objects, strings, etc.    
    //...

    if (is_resource($mixed)) {
        return 'resource: ' . get_resource_type($mixed);
    }
    return gettype($mixed) . ': ' . $mixed;
}
```

Even when I use code by `diz at ysagoon dot com` listed under [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) documentation, which utilize `gettype()` and check for `resource`, in my case it returns `Config->saveToFile(Unknown)`.

When I use the methods in code where the resource is created, it correctly returns its type.

Is there a limit or reason why resources are not identified from backtrace? Something I should enable in PHP configuration? I haven't found anything about this in PHP documentation nor Google.

---

System:

- XAMPP 3.2.2
- Apache/2.4.17 (Win32)
- PHP/5.6.15
- Windows 10 Pro x64 Anniversary edition 1607 (10.0.14393)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that **resources can be identified as a `resource` only while they are opened**. After you close the resource, it is no more identified by methods `gettype()`, `is_resource()` and `get_resource_type()` as a `resource` and instead change to `unknown type`.

```
$f = fopen('tmp', 'w');
echo gettype($f); //= 'resource'
fclose($f);
echo gettype($f); //= 'Unknown type'
```

---

To print closed resources in backtrace I've created two methods to remember resources while they are still opened:

```
protected $resources = [];

public function traceResourceParams() {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $args = [];
    foreach ($trace as $call) {
        foreach ($call['args'] as $arg) {
            if (is_resource($arg) && !array_key_exists(intval($arg), $this->resources)) {
                $this->resources[intval($arg)] = self::toString($arg);
            }
        }
    }
}

public function traceNamedResource($resource, $name) {
    if (is_resource($resource)) {
        $this->resources[intval($resource)] = '{' . get_resource_type($resource) . ': ' . $name . '}';
    }
}
```

And updated my `toString` method to check for stored resources:

```
protected static function toString($mixed) {
    //process known types - arrays, objects, strings, etc.    
    //...

    if (is_resource($mixed)) {
        return 'resource: ' . get_resource_type($mixed);
    }

    //closed resources does not evaluate as resource
    //but still convert to resource id using intval()
    //so we can match them to previously evaluated resources
    $val = intval($mixed);
    if ($val && array_key_exists($val, self::getInstance()->resources)) {
        return self::getInstance()->resources[$val];
    }

    return gettype($mixed) . ': ' . $mixed;
}
```

---

So now I can store the resource when it is created:

```
$f = fopen('tmp', 'w');
$debug->traceNamedResource($f, 'tmp');
fclose($f);
```

Or when it is passed as a parameter:

```
protected function saveToFile($file) {
        $debug->traceResourceParams()

        //... work with file

        fclose($file);
}
```